# MySQL rollback in handler

Tags: php, mysql, handler, sqlexception

I have a stored procedure where I'd like to rollback in case anything goes wrong. In order to do that I'm using a EXIT HANDLER like this:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception 
    begin
        ROLLBACK;
    end;
```

But in this way, when I call this stored procedure, in case of any errors, the stored procedure succeed and I don't know what was the actual problem. I want the client (php) to log the error in order to troubleshoot it. So I modify in this way:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception 
    begin
        get diagnostics condition 1
              @p1 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        ROLLBACK;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @p1;
    end;
```

So now the stored procedure rollback and than throw the exeption that the handler intercepted. That's cool but sometimes the MESSAGE_TEXT is more than 128 chars and in such cases I get:

> Error Code: 1648. Data too long for condition item 'MESSAGE_TEXT'

Of course this solution is not acceptable:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception 
    begin
        get diagnostics condition 1
              @p1 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        ROLLBACK;
        SET @p1=SUBSTRING(@p1,1,128);
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @p1;
    end;
```

Is there any way to intercept any exception, rollback and then throw the same exception to the client?
Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Where do you `BEGIN` the transaction? Also in a stored procedure, or in PHP?

Comment: In the stored procedure. Of course also the commit is inside the stored procedure

Comment: Ok thanks. Perhaps [RESIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resignal.html) is what you're looking for? It should pass on the original error.

Comment: It did the trick. Thanks so much, I missed that function on the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by Kenney the answer is:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception 
    begin
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;
    end;
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this template and it works for me. When exceptions are encountered, transaction flow immediately jumps to `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION`. The last statement to be executed by MySQL engine would be `ROLLBACK`. After that, transaction flow moves out of the `tblock`

Handle the exceptions gracefully by returning the **error codes** and **message** as recordset (not throwing an error to PHP), which your PHP code can easily manipulate and display.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `ProcName`( <parameters here> )
BEGIN

    START TRANSACTION;

    tblock: BEGIN # start: transaction block

        /* catch any exceptions, then rollback */
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
                @state = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
                @rtc    = MYSQL_ERRNO,
                @rmg    = MESSAGE_TEXT; -- MySQL 5.6 > : comment diagnostics for lower versions
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

        /* table transactions here */

        COMMIT;

    END tblock; # end: transaction block

    SELECT  @rtc AS retcode,
            @rmg AS retmsg,
            'some ret value' AS retval;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In SQL, as standard, 0 is success and non-zero (usually greater than zero) values suggest error. You may want to follow such and make it a practice.